# Validação de Entrada de Valor Float no Python

Tags: python

Quero solcitar uma entrada de valor ao usuário através de um input e quero validar se ele digitou um float ou não.

Mas eu não sei como validar isso através de um input, uma vez que os dados estão vindo em formato de string.

Alguém consegue me ajudar?